# Get image coordinate for click event in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I make main page works like, for each of the attached image, on click it will go to new animal content page. I don't want to use image map on the web.
Is there any way to do like this in Xamarin forms, if not how will be the custom render for android/ios
[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdWsJ.png)

Comment: A Forms-based `TapGestureRecognizer` does not provide x/y coordinates, you would need to implement custom renders on each platform you are targeting.

Comment: how will be the event in Xamarin Android and IOS?